# Remove cookie/local storage on browser close, but not page refresh or new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-hooks

In my React app, I am looking to use either a Cookie/Local storage for some state. So I want

1. Cookie/Local storage to be set on initial load (based on state from server)
2. Cookie/Local storage should be retained on page refresh/new tab
3. Cookie/Local storage should be cleared on browser close

Also, I would prefer a React dependency for either cookie/local storage solution.

Comment: sessionStorage be the choice.

Comment: As ProGu said, session storage is the exact solution your use case requires. Also cookies/session storage are just general Javascript things, they've got nothing to do with React, so not sure what you mean by "React dependency" for them. Handling them with vanilla JS is very simple

Comment: Session storage is not retained when we open a new tab...So unfortunately that won't help here...

Comment: Is there something different in your setup? Session storage should be retained when you open a new tab.

Comment: Please carefully read the MDN Web Docs first on [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), I think the explanations there are good enough to answer your question. If not, you may come back here for some clarifications.

Comment: @nontechguy - See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
It says "Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
"

Comment: @copenndthagen, that is correct. Opening a new tab or window will create a new session storage for that tab or window. Going back to the original tab will retain that tab or windows session storage. Session storage meets your three criteria unless your are expecting the session storage to be shared between tabs or windows?